# Failed to connect to server (When ROS is connected to the robot)

Tags: ros, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm having difficulty connecting to my fanuc robot with ROS Melodic. I followed this tutorial to configure "http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials". When I send this command：

```
robot_interface_streaming.launch robot_ip:=192.168.20.22 J23_factor:=0 use_bswap:=true
```

I got this error:

```
Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection refused' (errno: 111)
Failed to receive message lenth
Failed to receive  incoming message
```

when I `ping 192.168.20.22`, I received responses from the robot. So I don't know what went wrong, or did I configure something wrong? Does the operation of the Fanuc controller require any operation, which I do not know at this time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417753/failed-to-connect--to-server-(when-ros-is-connected-to-the-robot)/) by [787500229](https://answers.ros.org/users/166056/787500229/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, and pedantic, but: Melodic is EOL. There is no support for it any more.

As to your connection issue: I'd suggest to make sure you installed everything on the robot controller as well, and have started the TP programs on the Fanuc teach pendant. Without those programs, the ROS nodes will not be able to connect.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [787500229](https://answers.ros.org/users/166056/787500229/) on 2023-07-30**:
Thank you, I noticed that Fanuc's TP program was not activated.